# How can I iterate through all my vector elements and check their variables? (C++)

Tags: c++

So I have a problem with my C++ game. If I try to use an item that has the quantity <= than 0, it will work. How can I prevent the function from using the item if it's quantity is <= than 0?
Here is some of the code:

**Use item function**

```cpp
void Inventory::useItem(int id, int quantity, Character &character)
{
    if (id == 2 && !isNull())
    {
        removeQuantity(2, 1);
        cout << "\n" << "You used the item with Id 2!" << endl;
        character.addOrbs(100);
    }
    else
    {
        setColor(0x0C);
        cout << "\n" << "ERROR! ";
        setColor(0x07);
        cout << "There is no item with such ID!" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Check if item quantity is 0 function**

```cpp
bool Inventory::isNull()
{
    for(auto &item : inventoryVec)
    {
        if (item.quantity <= 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you hit the return you function ends. You probably want to move `return false;` to the end of the function if you want it to return true if any value in your vector is less than or equal to 0.

Comment: The first question is what does the isNull function suppose to do?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @drescherjm I did it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Should `isNull` return `true` both in cases where the `Item` with the given `id` is not in the `inventoryVec` AND when its quantity is `<= 0`, or are all searched for items guaranteed to be in the `inventoryVec`?

Comment: Maybe I not understanding what cases isNull should return true. My suggestion was to make it return true if any quantity in the vector was less than or equal to 0. However the rules were not fully explained.

Comment: @dr I *think* `isNull` should return `true` if a *particular* `Item`s quantity is <= 0, but we're pending information from OP to see if that's what they intended.

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] and a better description what exactly is Null should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isNull()` method is checking if only *the 1st item* in the inventory, regardless of its `id`, has a quantity of `<= 0`.  It is ignoring *all other* items.

What you should be doing instead is looking *specifically* for the item with an id of 2, and then checking if that item has a quantity of `<= 0`, eg:

```cpp
bool Inventory::isNull(int id)
{
    for(auto &item : inventoryVec)
    {
        if (item.id == id)
            return (item.quantity <= 0);
    }
    return true;
}

void Inventory::useItem(int id, int quantity, Character &character)
{
    if ((id == 2) && !isNull(id))
    {
        removeQuantity(2, 1);
        cout << "\n" << "You used the item with Id 2!" << endl;
        character.addOrbs(100);
    }
    else
    {
        setColor(0x0C);
        cout << "\n" << "ERROR! ";
        setColor(0x07);
        cout << "There is no item with such ID!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Though, I would suggest changing `useItem()` to be more like this instead:

```cpp
void Inventory::useItem(int id, int quantity, Character &character)
{
    if (!isNull(id))
    {
        removeQuantity(id, 1);
        cout << "\n" << "You used the item with Id " << id << "!" << endl;
        if (id == 2)
            character.addOrbs(100);
        else
            ... // handle other ids as needed...
    }
    else
    {
        setColor(0x0C);
        cout << "\n" << "ERROR! ";
        setColor(0x07);
        cout << "There is no item with such ID!" << endl;
    }
}
```